# Append text to existing file c++

Tags: c++

I have this text cpp application which i am working with.
I want  to make some text append on a already created txt file.
The text file name is "PatientDatabase.txt" and the formatting is like this:

```
CPR             Patient nr      Værelse nr      Seng nr     Medicin
2568875874      268             69              52      
2543875874      168             49              12
2568874574      368             59              42
2560175874      968             39              92
```

I want to `append` text to the "Medicin" section, so i would get like the following:

```
CPR             Patient nr      Værelse nr      Seng nr     Medicin
2568875874      268             69              52          D vitamin, Cholesterol, C vitamin 
2543875874      168             49              12          Iron, B-vit, Herb
2568874574      368             59              42          Multi vit, Liver
2560175874      968             39              92          Ginesing, Protein powder
```

So the thing i want to do is to append costum text in the end of a specific line which i choose through CPR number

I hope you can help!

My application is pretty large, but to find something in the TXT file, i have made the following code:

```
string CPRF;
cout << "Her kan du søge i databasen" << endl;
cout << "\nFor at bruge denne funktion skal du finde patienten via. CPR nr." << endl;
int cf2 = 0;
while (cf2 == 0)
{
    cout << "Indtast patientens CPR nr. FORMAT: xxxxxx-xxxx: ";
    cin >> CPRF;
    CPRF.erase(remove(CPRF.begin(), CPRF.end(), '-'), CPRF.end());

    ifstream filein("c:/hospitaldata/PatientDatabase.txt");

    string strTemp;
    while (getline(filein, strTemp))
    {
        if (strTemp.find(CPRF) != string::npos)
        {
            cout << "CPR\t\t\tPatient nummer\t\tVærelse nr\t\tSeng nr" << endl;
            cout << strTemp << endl;
            cf2++;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Kunne ikke finde patienten, Prøv igen" << endl;
        }
    }

}
```

**Notice: The CPR numbers(Personal identification number) are useless, as i just typed some digits.**

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having? That you don't know how to append text to a file? Open it in append mode, or seek to the end of it, then write to it. Or is something failing in your code? Or... what?

Comment: Do you need to do this one line at a time, or can you read the whole file, make changes, then write the whole file?  You can't really insert text into the middle of the file.

Comment: Update: So the thing i want to do is to append costum text in the end of a specific line which i choose through CPR number.

Yea i could read the whole file and then append text

Comment: This really seems like you should be using SQLITE or some other database format instead of straight flatfile.

Comment: Maybe. My idea was to find a specific word (in this case a 10 digit number) and find the line number of it, and append text to end of the specific line.